# how to integrate/connect apache nifi ingestion processor to Apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I want to push data from one of the ingestion processor of Apache nifi to Kafka and further to HDFS for storage.

Is it possible to connect the ingestion processor of Apache nifi with Kafka?

Comment: https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/09/15/apache-nifi-and-apache-kafka

Answer (score 5):

Nifi ships with several Kafka processors.

Just start typing Kafka into search box when you add one. Use the version that matches your Kafka installation. For example, absolutely don't run Kafka08 version processor (called GetKafka & PutKafka) with a Kafka 0.10.x installation

You'll need to set the bootstrap servers, of course, then whatever other producer properties you care about, like the topic name

Attach a ConsumeKafka processor to PutHdfs

---

Sidenote [Kafka Connect HDFS](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) uses purely Kafka based API methods to ship data to Hadoop from Kafka. You don't require Nifi unless you're ingesting some other types of data

Answer (score 0):

You can use PutKafka processors for pushing data from Nifi to Kafka. In Add Processors dialog, type PutKafka for find the processor.

For HDFS, you can use PutHDFS processor. You need core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files to use PutHDFS processor. You can download HDFS configuration files from HDFS menu inside Ambari. In HDFS menu, click Actions and select Download Client Configs. You should write file locations by comma seperated.